# troubles with exceptions in python Codio exercise

Tags: python, exception, except

I  have the following code that also calls the function below.
it loads files which can have text like that

**sample 1** (it should return corrupted file)
101 90 20,
abracadabra 45 30

**sample 2** (in this case the the function raise value error)
101 90 20
122 50 70

**sample 3** (in this case the function does fine the computation)
101 90 20
122 70 50

**Additionally**; if the user enter a non existing file it will also rise an error.

**The problem:**
My code below works fine except that prints out the value of s in any case, I just want to print the exeptions or the computation when the file is good.

**More to the above.**
if I remove the print from the function it will catch all the exceptions fine but it will not print out the result in case the numbers are of the right kind

```
from calculate_mark import calculate_mark

try:
  
  infile= open(input("enter a file name" ), "r" )

  s=infile.read().splitlines()
  
  for x in s:
    print (calculate_mark(x))

except SyntaxError:
  print("Corrupt file.")

except ValueError:
  print("Values are not correct.")

except FileNotFoundError:
  print("The file does not exist.")


finally:
  infile.close()
```

```
def calculate_mark(s):
  parts = s.split()
  if len(parts)!=3: raise SyntaxError
  for part in parts:
    if not part.isdigit(): raise SyntaxError
      
  mark = int(parts[1])
  penalty = int(parts[2])
  if penalty > mark: raise ValueError
  return parts[0]+" "+str(mark-penalty)
```

The outout put from codio is

```
Check 1 passed
Check 2 failed
Output:
101 70
Corrupt file.
Expected:
Corrupt file.
Feedback:
We tried with marks_file_4.txt in the Filetree.
Check 3 failed
Output:
101 70
Values are not correct.
Expected:
Values are not correct.
Feedback:
We tried with marks_file_5.txt in the Filetree.
Check 4 passed
Show diff
```

Comment: In the example cases you gave, did you mean to have 3 values in each line? `101 marks penalty`. Instead of the 6 that it looks like in your examples?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what your problem is. Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: I have added the output from codio

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because the error does not have to be in the first line of your txt file.
This means that if the corrupted part is the first line of your file, the code will work as intended, and otherwise it will compute the first line and later find the error.

**for example:**

```
abracadabra 45 30    #issue found, outputs corrupt file
101 90 20
```

`Output: Corrupt file.`

```
101 90 20        # No issue in this part, outputs computation
abracadabra 45 30   # issue found after, outputs corrupt file
```

```
Output:
101 70
Corrupt file.
```

**To solve the issue:**
We have to check all the lines for issues before putting any output.

My solution would be to add a function that checks all the lines for validity, and then follow that with the calculate function (with the below modification):

```py
# Add this function
def check_validity(lines):
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split(" ")
        if len(parts) != 3: raise SyntaxError
        if any(part.isdigit() is False for part in parts): raise SyntaxError
        
        mark = int(parts[1])
        penalty = int(parts[2])
        if penalty > mark: raise ValueError


#And change the calculate function as so:
def calculate_marks(line):
    parts = line.split(" ")
    
    mark = int(parts[1])
    penalty = int(parts[2])
    if penalty > mark:raise ValueError
    return parts[0]+" "+str(mark-penalty)

# remaining code
try:
    with open(input("enter a file name: " ), "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        
        ### Utilising our new function ###
        check_validity(lines)

        for line in lines:
            calculate_marks(line)


except SyntaxError:
    print("Corrupt file.")

except ValueError:
    print("Values are not correct.")

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("The file does not exist.")
```